# JSON object sort in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON object jobj=JSON.parse(jsnstr) array returned by JSON.parse and I wish to sort it by its name.
I have used

```
jobj=$(jobj).sort(sortfunction);
 function sortfunction(a,b){  
     return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
 };
```

But this didnt work out instead i am getting undefined obj any help?

Comment: Your code as-is looks sound, we would need your JSON string to investigate further.

Comment: Can you show us what `jsnstr` looks like?

Answer (score 3):

You can't sort a hash; it must be an array. What you can do is setup the reference of each a.name value to an array and then sort that array with a custom function like you have up there.

```
json = JSON.parse(...);
var refs = [];
for(var i in json) {
  var name = i.name;
  refs.push({
    name : name.toLowerCase(),
    object : i
  });
}

var sorted = refs.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.name > b.name;
});
```

Now everything in your refs array is sorted and you can access each object individually by sorted[index].object.

Comment: +1 for "you can't sort a hash". The other answers seem to assume that it's an array. Without seeing the json code, that's a gratuitous assumption.

Comment: I didnt work apparently when I looked at the object.The object was a hash some number not the required however previously the object was object. but thanks for telling me the fact that "I cant sort a hash" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write this:

```
jobj=$(jobj).sort(function(a,b){  
     return a.name.toLowerCase() > b.name.toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1;  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this.  Also, `sort` modifies the original array.  So, if `jobj` is an array, you can just do:

```
jobj.sort(sortfunction);
```

You may also want to account for the case where `a.name` and `b.name` are the same:

```
function sortfunction(a,b){  
    var aSort = a.name.toLowerCase(),
        bSort = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if(aSort === bSort) return 0;
    return aSort > bSort ? 1 : -1;  
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xmmPL/